# How can I sign a contract and get acces to make transactions without the users confirmation?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereumjs

Let's say that I made a dapp where the user is signing a contract, and the amount he selected for his NFT payment, is automaticlly transfered withou any confirmation?

Comment: Please explain better.

Comment: For example, i have seen on youtube that the developers use eth_sign method to sign a contract that offer them the acces to the account and can make a transaction without the confirmation pop-up without using solidity

Comment: We have user A and the website.
User A signs a contract, and then the website transfers automaticlly the amount of eth the user A has selected from the cart.

Comment: please provide an example of what you're talking about

Comment: let signature = await ethereum.request({ method: 'signTypedData_v4', params: [ transactionParameters] });


And then using sendRawtransaction to make the transaction withou confirmation pop-up, is it possible without solidity? Just javascript

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an implementation of EIP-712, which is a method of allowing users to sign approvals and transfers gas free.

Have a read through these articles which might help.

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712

https://medium.com/metamask/eip712-is-coming-what-to-expect-and-how-to-use-it-bb92fd1a7a26

https://soliditydeveloper.com/erc721-permit

Comment: But somehow just using javascript?

Comment: Without solidity or node.js

Comment: you are asking if you can force a user to transfer assets without permission? of course not. please be specific or provide real examples

Comment: Of course with his permission, like, the user signs a contract, and then he selects some nfts from the website that I've created, and he just hits the buton pay, and automaticly the eth is being sent in the companies account, and then the user gets the nfts.
Like, he signs a contract, which is broadcasted, but for every transaction he is not putted under the ideea to confirm every transaction that is made

Comment: that is not how transactions work, the user must sign something at some point for each transaction. you need to work on the terminology because 'signing a contract' does not make sense in the context of ethereum at all.